# What are the restrictions in the AWS lambda.invoke function relevant to Region where the lambdas are located?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, invoke, region

I would like to know what are the restrictions in order to invoke a lambda inside another lambda function. Are there any restrictions concerning the Region? can I invoke a lambda function from a different region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AWS Lambda function can be invoked from anywhere on the Internet, including from other Lambda functions, even from different regions.

Simply ensure you are making the call using a `client` that been given the desired region. For example, in Python:

```
import boto3

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region='ap-southeast-2')
```